Is true that English speakers pronounce /i/ as /e/ ~ /ɛ/ when yelling?
As far as I can remember, it is a common practice in songs to pronounce expected /i/ as /e/ ~ /ɛ/. The example that comes to my mind now is Turn me on from David Guetta:

My body needs a hero, come and save me
Something tells me you know how to save me
I've been feeling weird, oh
Oh, I need you to come and rescue ME

Second example: One Step Closer from Linkin Park

Everything you say to ME
Takes me one step closer to the edge
And I'm about to break
I need a little room to BREATHE
'Cause I'm one step closer to the edge
I'm about to break

Third example: Bring Me to Life, from Evanescence:

(Wake me up) Wake me up inside
(I can't wake up) Wake me up inside
(Save ME) Call my name and save me from the dark
(Wake me up) Bid my blood to run
(I can't wake up) Before I come undone
(Save ME) Save me from the nothing I've become

Fourth example: Don't Stop the Music, from Rihanna, though is not yelling at all:

Please don't stop the music
Please don't stop the MUSIC
(is the last ‘music’ on the bridge just before the last chorus, around 3:10)

Fifth example: Bohemian Rhapsody, from Queen

So you think you can stone me and spit in my eye?
So you think you can love me and leave me to die?
Oh, BABY, can't do this to me, BABY
Just gotta get out, just gotta get right outta here

Is this common for natives in everyday speaking? Or is just some kind of non standard fashion imposed by music industry?

An audio example would be helpful here. But, while not being able to what you're talking about, I would say it's definitely not standard at all (either in everyday speech or in the music industry).

I believe this is partly a stylistic affectation, but mostly due to the fact that /iː/ is [ɪj] for many speakers, and [ɪ] is quite close to [e].

@PeterShor more examples 4u

Links to audio(video)?

Choir singers pronounce vowels differently when singing than speaking. I am not sure that this is a fashion imposed by the music industry; the practice may well pre-date recorded music. You might get interesting responses to a question about singers' pronunciation on Music: Practice and Theory SE.

Is this about yelling or singing? Not the same thing.

@StuartF usually they are not the same thing, but often they are.

Although the happY vowel has shifted from [ɪ] to [i] in prestige accents of both the UK and the US in the 20th century, [ɪ] remains in Southern American English and Black English. Lowered realizations of happY are also common in singing, sometimes broken into a diphthong like [eɪ], to evoke those accents and sound stereotypically country, rock, blues, etc.
As this blog put it:

A singer’s decision to say ‘happih’ when they may normally say ‘happy’ is the result of a century-long process of imitating and ultimately de-racializing African American English pronunciations. Depending on which point in the 20th century you choose, the choice of that pronunciation could reflect a desire to invoke old-fashioned RP, to sound like a black blues singer, or to simply sound current and “soulful”.


But there is also a tendency to open closed vowels when yelling.  I suspect that this is a stronger contributory factor in some styles than in others.

It is not only about imitating black American singers. It's also about pitch.

In that Turn me On song, sung my Nicki Menaj, she pronounces me two different ways herself: one way inside a sentence, another at the end of a sentence.  So the yelling thing is basically off-mark. It's a singing thing, not a yelling thing.  No one is imposing anything on anybody. When the word me is at the end, the sound can also be extended which doesn't mean the pronunciation is different.
Singers pronounce things as they see fit but please read this about compression, which changes a sound, like vowels:
compression and vowel sounds
For example, that article explains this:
1)

Strong-Armed by Vowels Vowel issues are especially easy to bump into when you sing with compression. To maintain original vowel
pronunciation during high notes, at some point, you’re forced to drop
compression. This makes your voice sound different and can even cause
unintentional voice cracks — something you’ll generally want to avoid.
As a singer, you naturally want to be in control of your vowels and
not be forced to change up your sound just so you can maintain the way
you pronounce certain vowels during high notes. Christina Aquilera is
a great example of a singer who can maintain compression during really
high notes by shifting the way she sings the vowels. Every once in a
while, she’ll drop compression for high notes, making her vocals sound
a bit more raspy. Presumably, that’s an artistic decision. Shakira
likes to do something similar. The Columbian singer likes to alternate
between singing with and without compression by briefly dropping
compression at the end of a line — a technique that almost sounds like
yodelling. Some singers are so skilled, they can maintain initial
vowel pronunciation going into seriously high notes. Dutch singer
Marco Borsato is one of those singers. “Borsato pulls it off through
his superb breathing technique and exceptional endurance”, says vocal
coach Alfons Verreijt. “He takes in just enough air, keeping the
internal pressure to the bare minimum. This way, his vowel
pronunciation barely needs to shift. He has also mastered breath
support and barely has to expand his sides, giving him a big margin
when he gets to the tricky notes. Borsato doesn’t sing loudly but he
does sing full of pep, which helps him control his vowels and maintain
compression during the higher notes, while applying twang lends
intensity to his vowels.
Pioneer Cathrine Sadolin Thanks to Danish vocal coach Cathrine
Sadolin, you really don’t need to be Shakira to sing well and
comfortably dodge vowel issues. Founder of the well-known Complete
Vocal Technique (CVT), Sadolin has done groundbreaking work analysing
the vowel pronunciation of a large number of singers. “She discovered
that many singers change the way they sing vowels when going up in
pitch,” Alfons says. “That way, they can maintain the original
timbre”. Sadolin’s method involves changing the pronunciation of
certain vowels to ‘uh’ (as in ‘luck’), ‘i’ (as in ‘sit’) and ‘oh’ (as
in ‘long’), which Alfons thinks is a solid and practical solution,
even if it’s a solution that has its limitations. “You constantly have
to be aware of which vowels change into those ‘uh’, ‘i’ and ‘oh’
sounds and at which pitch the shift should take place. In other words,
there are strict guidelines that need to be followed, which is extra
difficult for multilingual singers because vowel pronunciation differs
between different languages. That’s actually why I started thinking
about a different approach, one that feels more natural for singers.”
Here's the chart"


2)

There's actually no right or wrong vowel pronunciation, it has more to do with how you pronounce your words and how you want to sound
style-wise in the song that you're singing. For example, someone from
the deep south will pronounce their syllables differently than someone
from the mid-west, so it really just depends on how you want your
words to sound when you're singing. Also, pronunciation can vary
from genre to genre. Jeannie notes that she would sing the line
differently if it were in a country music context as opposed to
something more bluesy.
You can change tones and vowel pronunciations as long as you know what
the vowel sound is. As singers, we are painters with sound. Much as a
painter needs to know colors so that they can be mixed together to
create different shades and dimensions, singers need to know vowel
sounds.
A lot of our vowel pronunciations are combinations of sounds, like the
word "your" for example also contains that "r" consonant sound.
Consonant sounds constrict, they crush your vowels and constrict your
muscles.
For the word "eyes", it actually contains an "ahh" sound as opposed to "eee", so you want to sing it more like "ahhhhs" than "eyeeeees".
Next word is "wide" - which also contains an "ah" vowel sound.
A fun vocal exercise you can do to practice singing vowels is to write
out a song's lyrics and slowly say each word. This will help you
recognize and discover the heart of each word is without the tongue
closing.

sing better vowels and consonants

/i/ vowel singing, as in me, unconstricted

/i/ vowel
To answer the question really well, one would have to know the singer's actual accent, then compare that to their singing accent, of a sound like /i/. That said, in the Nicki Menaj rendition of the Guetta song, she pronounces me in two ways: In Give me something and Come and rescue me, she uses /i/ mostly and also extends its sound and she also does /ɛ/
I didn't listen to all the songs but if the me is not only pronounced with /i/ or extended /i/, generally, the other would be me would be sung as /ɛ/ as in eh.
